# CefSharp javascript injected elements inside paragraph cause ignoring its padding

Tags: javascript, html, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am injecting javascript inside the CefSharp browser. It works well, except for some strange behavior that only happens with CefSharp. The paragraph's padding is somehow ignored after injecting span tags inside it.

This is what it looks like in Chrome and Chromium:

[image]

This is what it looks like in CefSharp:

[image]

This is what it looks like in CefSharp with DevTools:

[image]

This is what the resulting HTML structure looks like:

[image]

I could easily think of a work around, but I'd like to know what the issue is here.

**Update:**

This is a problem with native HTML, without any javascript injections. Here is a comparison with on the left CefSharp (v55.0.0, redist: v3.2883.1552), on the right Chromium (Version 60.0.3077.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit)):

[image]

I notice the rendering is different.

Comment: Did you use CEF's DevTools to debug actual DOM tree / styles in wrong case?

Comment: @fddima added an image with the result from using DevTools. The padding does seem to exist, but it seems like it is added around the contents. The HTML source is identical.

Comment: My best bet is that difference in layout exist (somewhere above?). And foreignObject just has wrong coords. At least colors differs at your screens, so may be something also different. I'm not sure what you mean by injecting script at all... I.e. if you connect this to script injection - then try inject unrelated script to see that injecting is not issue at all. If so - then problem in script's job?

Comment: @fddima The coordinates of the foreignObject don't change. The color is based on wheter a value is true or false, it shouldn't matter. The script's job is to add spans around contents of the paragraph tag. The script is copied from the project that I use to test in Chromium. The script works fine, otherwise their would be no spans added, and no red color in the image above.

Comment: Then i suggest to reproduce this with chrome. If it is not reproducible this can be layouting bug what already fixed (but usually can be reproduced with same version of chromium that's used in concrete CEF build).

Comment: About coordinates - you image looks like one text line shift of whole text block. In one case it is present and in second is not. *Looks like.* So basically i think it is bug in resulting tree (script?). No more have ideas, sorry. :)

Comment: @fddima I tried and disabled all script injections, it seems a problem with native HTML. I will try and find out what version of Chromium CefSharp is using and try the file on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Chromium 57.0 / CEF 3.2987.1601(Chromium 57.0.2987.133) solved the problem. There was a rending mismatch between versions of Chromium.

[image]